# How to install and use Onsen2.0 right in cordova

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, onsen-ui2

I want to make my Cordova Apps with the Onsen2.0 framework because it looks very cool for android and ios. How do I have to use it when developing cordova Apps. I always used materialize.css where you only had to download a .css and a .js file and import that to your project. Why is it know so different, how do you have to do it now? Also I have read something about Monaca CLI what is it and why do I have to do something too with that? Just want to have the cool design framework from Onsen2.0.